# Cloning repository with submodules

Tags: github

I am trying to make a clone of a https://github.com/owncloud/news-iOS-App repository which contains several submodules. I've been pointed to do recursive cloning and did some searching on SO. It seems that it should be simple:

```
 git clone --recursive
```

Unfortunately, that got me where i started, and i can't seem to figure it out. This is whole terminal dialog:

```
ctsi-macmini:Documents ivan$ git clone --recursive https://github.com/owncloud/news-iOS-App.git
Cloning into 'news-iOS-App'...
remote: Counting objects: 2973, done.
remote: Total 2973 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 2973
Receiving objects: 100% (2973/2973), 6.88 MiB | 502.00 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (1845/1845), done.
Submodule 'AFNetworking' (https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking.git) registered for path 'AFNetworking'
Submodule 'JCGridMenu' (https://github.com/joecarney/JCGridMenu.git) registered for path 'JCGridMenu'
Submodule 'KSCrash' (https://github.com/kstenerud/KSCrash.git) registered for path 'KSCrash'
Submodule 'MMDrawerController' (https://github.com/mutualmobile/MMDrawerController.git) registered for path 'MMDrawerController'
Submodule 'MMDrawerController-Storyboard' (https://github.com/TomSwift/MMDrawerController-Storyboard.git) registered for path 'MMDrawerController-Storyboard'
Submodule 'Objective-C-HTML-Parser' (git://github.com/tresni/Objective-C-HMTL-Parser.git) registered for path 'Objective-C-HTML-Parser'
Submodule 'PDKeychainBindingsController' (https://github.com/carlbrown/PDKeychainBindingsController.git) registered for path 'PDKeychainBindingsController'
Submodule 'SDWebImage' (https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage.git) registered for path 'SDWebImage'
Submodule 'TSMessages' (https://github.com/toursprung/TSMessages.git) registered for path 'TSMessages'
Submodule 'TUSafariActivity' (https://github.com/davbeck/TUSafariActivity.git) registered for path 'TUSafariActivity'
Submodule 'readable' (https://github.com/JanX2/readable.git) registered for path 'readable'
Cloning into '/Users/ivan/Documents/news-iOS-App/AFNetworking'...
Cloning into '/Users/ivan/Documents/news-iOS-App/JCGridMenu'...
Cloning into '/Users/ivan/Documents/news-iOS-App/KSCrash'...
Cloning into '/Users/ivan/Documents/news-iOS-App/MMDrawerController'...
Cloning into '/Users/ivan/Documents/news-iOS-App/MMDrawerController-Storyboard'...
Cloning into '/Users/ivan/Documents/news-iOS-App/Objective-C-HTML-Parser'...
Cloning into '/Users/ivan/Documents/news-iOS-App/PDKeychainBindingsController'...
Cloning into '/Users/ivan/Documents/news-iOS-App/SDWebImage'...
Cloning into '/Users/ivan/Documents/news-iOS-App/TSMessages'...
Cloning into '/Users/ivan/Documents/news-iOS-App/TUSafariActivity'...
Cloning into '/Users/ivan/Documents/news-iOS-App/readable'...
Submodule path 'AFNetworking': checked out '88f13053b1d1f20bf657f5c36459b87a5d317ad7'
error: no such remote ref 7375ddeb8db22b9c73c8db2ddd810652c23e19ea
Fetched in submodule path 'JCGridMenu', but it did not contain 7375ddeb8db22b9c73c8db2ddd810652c23e19ea. Direct fetching of that commit failed.
```

On the other hand, my teammate managed to clone some of the submodules on his computer calling the same command, but not the whole thing.

If you have any hints i would be grateful.

Answer (score 1):

The normal procedure to check out submodule is

clone the MainProject then go to the project and run

$ git submodule init 
$ git submodule update

The other way is the one you did 
$ git clone --recursive .
if you are still getting the error go to the .git directory and open the config file. make sure the submodule mentioned have the correct URL.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, the problem is that the parent repository at https://github.com/owncloud/news-iOS-App contains a submodule reference to the https://github.com/joecarney/JCGridMenu repository. The specific commit referenced there is not reachable (anymore) from any branch or tag however. It appears the commit was pushed by accident and later removed with a force-push again.

Thus, in general, your approach is fine. In this case, the parent repository has invalid references which need to be fixed by the repository owner.

Comment: thank you for replying. If i understood correctly, there is nothing i could do? It has to be fixed by the repository owner? 
Also, i contacted one of the contributors and what he told me is:
It’s because it’s trying to clone master, but you actually need a branch called iocnews of JCGridMenu.
I'm quite confused because JCGridMenu doesn't have any branches (as far as i can see).